# Money Transfer with invalid IBAN

Tags: wire-transfer, europe, italy

i made transfer with missing 1 number in IBAN so its invalid but the money never back into my account. In fact when my bank made correspondence, it is said that the money in credited to individual and this individual doesn't give authorization for the bank to debit the account back. In the first place how come the bank can add 1 number to the invalid IBAN, are they allow to do that? What are my options now? Do filing a police report easy in Italy, anyone ever filed it?

Comment: If you drop a number from the IBAN, it is invalid, so that should never have worked to begin with.

Comment: Yeah. THe whole idea of IBAN is that is includes a checksum. Missing out 1 number makes it invalid in 90% of the cases as in the checksum does not match and the account number either matches or does not match, period. Given that Italy is in the EU there must be some ombudsman system where you can complain to a third party.

Comment: @TomTom I think it should be even 99%.

Comment: Get in touch with the bank and start a complaint following their complaint process. Did you visit the bank in person ? Or if you had a chat over the phone, probably the support person gave you the wrong information. Call again.

Comment: Can you advise the position of the digit you missed? Italy doesn't have check digit... The IBAN check digit doesn't consider the branch code... So it can pass check sum. However receiving bank should have validated for length and failed... It's possible that receiver bank has incorrect processing and make be added a leading zero to account number and transferred to an account in incorrect branch...

Comment: @Dheer Wrong. The IBAN check digits (position 3 and 4) consider all positions except themselves. In all countries. Maybe you confuse that with the creditor ID, where the three positions after the check digits (usually ZZZ) are left out of the calculation.